# Javascript Object appears then disappears Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a factory which does a HTTP get to a php script.

The php script returns the proper data to the factory which then sends its data to the controller:

```
.controller('CatListController', ['$scope', 'Category', function ($scope, Category) {
$scope.categories = {};

var res = Category.list();

console.log(res); // <-- shows the proper object
console.log(res.data); //<-- shows nothing

if (res.error) {
    $scope.error = true;
    $scope.message = "http error";
}else{
    if (res.data.error) {
        $scope.error = true;
        $scope.message = "database error";
    }
    $scope.categories = res.data;
}
  }]);
```

the first console log displays the full object in its entirety, but the next console log display an empty object.

the object that is supposed to shown is (and does from the console log res):

```
{
  data: { name: "" },
  error: false
}
```

why is this happening?

Comment: When you output the first message and get the object is `data` a property of the object?

Comment: yes, as shown in the object that is supposed to be shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is all right! Your first console.log prints an object. The browser keeps the output up to date with the state of the object. Keep in mind list() ist an asynchronous call, so the result will arrive later. The second console.log output prints a property of the object. The console did not update this if the data are arriving.

From the angular [$ressource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) documentation:

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data. This is a useful trick since usually the resource is assigned to a model which is then rendered by the view. Having an empty object results in no rendering, once the data arrives from the server then the object is populated with the data and the view automatically re-renders itself showing the new data. This means that in most cases one never has to write a callback function for the action methods.

Comment: could you elaborate more, Its a bit difficult to understand that

Comment: If it is asynchronous, then how do you get the information back? If it is using the `$resources`